# angular get data from called function in another view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, routes

How I can print data from function in function in controller on my view? I call function and send id of user and another view, but when I go on that view I can't get data, if I call again function from there I am loosing id.

My link on view allUsers:

```
<a href="#/editUser" ng-click="userDataCtr.updateUser(user.identities[0].user_id)">Edit</a>
```

My function in function userDataController called updateUser:

```
function updateUser(theId) {
        console.log(theId);
        dataService.allOrganization().then(function (data) {
            vm.allOrg = data;
        });
        dataService.getOneUser(theId).then(function(data) {
            vm.oneUserUpdate = data;
            vm.user={};
            vm.user.encryption = vm.oneUserUpdate.app_metadata.encryptionKey;
            vm.user.admin = vm.oneUserUpdate.app_metadata.admin;
            vm.user.organization = vm.oneUserUpdate.app_metadata.organizationId;
            if(vm.oneUserUpdate.app_metadata.roles[0] == 'ROLE_CRO') {
                vm.user.role_cro = 1;
            } else {
                vm.user.role_cro = 0;
            }
            if((vm.oneUserUpdate.app_metadata.roles[0] == 'ROLE_CLIENT') || (vm.oneUserUpdate.app_metadata.roles[1] == 'ROLE_CLIENT')) {
                vm.user.role_client = 1;
            } else {
                vm.user.role_client = 0;
            }
            console.log(vm.oneUserUpdate);
        });

        $scope.userDataCtr.user = {};
        $scope.submitForm = function(theId) {
            $scope.user.idUser = theId;
            dataService.updateUserPost($scope.user).then(function (data) {
                vm.oneUserInfo = data;
            })
        }
    }
```

And my application:

```
          $routeProvider.when('/editUser', {
            controller: 'userDataController',
            controllerAs: 'userDataCtr',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/users/editUser.html',
            requiresLogin: true
        });
```

As I said, if I in editUser.html make `<div ng-init="userDataCtr.updateUser()">` I am loosing id, but if I don't make div in this way I can't reach any data. I am confused, can anyone helps me? Thanks